# How should I save an Archicad project with furniture?

Tags: export, import

I work in ARCHICAD, and the projects I'm working on can be transferred to another computer. Despite the fact that I seem to be saving everything correctly, when I open the project on another computer, it appears there without furniture. What could be the problem and how to solve it.
I tried using both the same versions of the program and different ones.

Answer (score 1):

Archicad has a lot of [object libraries](https://graphisoft.com/downloads/parametric-objects) available.  I'd guess that your first computer has one of these installed, but the second computer is missing that same library.

Comment: Standart furniture dont save too